# get the returned value from php called page with json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The problem I am having is my current code does not display the values from my php_page.php.

I just double click on a photo and after this an input appears. I type a number in that input (for example 300) and when I blur the input my image comes back and it will show me the result from my php_page.php with JSON!

This is just a text script. I'm not looking for new ideas or different approaches at this point; I just want to know how I can modify my code to make it work.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">        </script>
 <style>
  .el{
  display: none;
  height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
     }
 .photo{
 width: 100px;
 height:100px;
 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <img src="ana.jpg" id="eu" class="photo" ></img>
  <input type="text" id="maine" class="el" value=" "></input>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#eu").on({
  dblclick:function ()
  {
   document.getElementById("maine").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("eu").style.display="none";
  }
  });
     }
    );
  $("#maine").on ({
   blur:function()
  {
  var blue=$("#maine").val();
  alert(blue);
  document.getElementById("maine").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("eu").style.display="block";
    var x="document";
        var dataString = "album" + blue;
            $.ajax({
 url: "php_page.php",
 type: "POST",
  dataType:'json',
  data: datastring,
  success: function(data){
   $("#responseArea").text(data);
    }
    });
       $('#maine').val(' ');
        }
    });
   </script>
   <p id="responseArea"> </p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

and my php page:

```
<?php
$ada=$_GET["album"];
echo (json_encode($ada));
?>
```

Comment: `type: "POST"` and `$_GET["album"]` seem a bit inconsistent. It should either be `type: "GET"` or `$_POST["album"]`

Comment: Use JSON.parse(data)

Comment: you may try to change: var dataString = "album" + blue; to: var dataString = {album:  blue};

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to over-engineer this. You can pass an object to the `ajax` function and jQuery will build the correct query for you. Also you need to use the `GET` type if you're to access the value via `$_GET`.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">        </script>
 <style>
  .el{
  display: none;
  height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
     }
 .photo{
 width: 100px;
 height:100px;
 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <img src="ana.jpg" id="eu" class="photo" ></img>
  <input type="text" id="maine" class="el" value=" "></input>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#eu").on({
  dblclick:function ()
  {
   document.getElementById("maine").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("eu").style.display="none";
  }
  });
     }
    );
  $("#maine").on ({
   blur:function()
  {
  var blue=$("#maine").val();
  alert(blue);
  document.getElementById("maine").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("eu").style.display="block";
    var x="document";
       
            $.ajax({
 url: "php_page.php",
 type: "GET",
  dataType:'json',
  data: { "album":  blue },
  success: function(data){
   $("#responseArea").text(data);
    }
    });
       $('#maine').val(' ');
        }
    });
   </script>
   <p id="responseArea"> </p>
   </body>
   </html>
```